# Displays the plugin layered popups

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I installed the plugin layeredpopups. But it does not work for me
I’ve tested the plugin on other sites, but it does not work on my site!
My site: artawp.com

Is js,jquery a problem?

Now I have the following js

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

tag head :

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

Before closing body
This code is located in the footer

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Hello
I use these codes
But pop-ups will not appear on my site

Comment: Add all your code, we can't help you if you only show this part

Comment: I added head and footer code

Comment: @JelmerBouman Can you guide me?

Comment: Where do you call the popups?

Comment: @JelmerBouman link demo for preview https://artawp.com/?ulp=CS5nbgWS6CYV4xG8&ac=Knoi9aUBdnf8dMq5#ulp-CS5nbgWS6CYV4xG8 The problem is that the preview is not displayed on my site. I do not know what the problem is